# How i set the data and update the data using array of objects in Flutter/Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have being trying to update the data from/to Firebase, but i have some issue, and when i update the data, in the firestore, the fields are being set in null value. How can i fix?

he error is just ocorring in the Armas object, the rest data in AtributteData is fine.

**MODEL**

```
class AtributeData {
  final List<int> atributtes;
  final List<int> perks;
  final List<int> customPerksValue;
  final List<String> customPerksName;
  final List<Armas> armas;

  AtributeData(
      {this.atributtes,
      this.perks,
      this.customPerksName,
      this.customPerksValue,
      this.armas});
}

class Armas {
  final String modelo;
  final int numero;
  final int preco;

  Armas({this.modelo, this.numero, this.preco});
}
```

**SCREEN WHEN I MAP THE DATA AND FUNCTION TO UPDATE DA DATA**

```
class AtributteDataService {
  final String uid;
  AtributteDataService({this.uid});

  //Referencia para uma Coleção específica
  final CollectionReference atributteSheet =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('atributteSheet');

  Future updateAtributteData(
      {List<int> atributtes,
      List<int> perks,
      List<int> customPerksValue,
      List<String> customPerksName,
      List<Armas> armas,
      String modelo,
      int numero,
      int preco}) async {
    return await atributteSheet.doc(uid).set({
      'atributtes': atributtes,
      'perks': perks,
      'customPerksValue': customPerksValue,
      'customPerksName': customPerksName,
      'armas': [
        {
          'modelo': modelo,
          'numero': numero,
          'preco': preco,
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  // retorna um snapshot, mas mapeado para AtributteData
  AtributeData _atributteDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return AtributeData(
        atributtes: List.from(snapshot['atributtes']),
        perks: List.from(snapshot['perks']),
        customPerksValue: List.from(snapshot['customPerksValue']),
        customPerksName: List.from(snapshot['customPerksName']),
        armas: List<Armas>.from(snapshot['armas'].map((e) {
          return new Armas(
            modelo: e["modelo"],
            numero: e["numero"],
            preco: e["preco"],
          );
        }))

        // markValue: List.from(snapshot['markValue']),
        );
  }

  //lista de todas as fichas dos usuários retornando em Stream

  //Obter Streams do Usuário (sem ser habilidades)
  Stream<AtributeData> get atributteData {
    return atributteSheet.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_atributteDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

TRY TO FILL THE DATA

```
  await AtributteDataService(uid: user.uid).updateAtributteData(
    armas: [
      Armas(modelo: 'G2', numero: 3, preco: 3200),
      Armas(modelo: 'M4A1', numero: 1, preco: 6400),
      Armas(modelo: 'AK-47', numero: 5, preco: 7500),
    ],
    customPerksName: [],
    customPerksValue: [],
    atributtes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    perks: [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
],
```

);

[FIREBASE IMAGE: FIELDS FILLED BY NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEHJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `.set()` without explicitly telling it to merge existing fields with the new updated ones.

To fix it, tell Firestore to merge your new data with existing ones by passing `SetOptions`:

```dart
return await atributteSheet.doc(uid).set({
      'atributtes': atributtes,
      'perks': perks,
      'customPerksValue': customPerksValue,
      'customPerksName': customPerksName,
      'armas': [
        {
          'modelo': modelo,
          'numero': numero,
          'preco': preco,
        }
      ]
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

More on this is explained in details [in the FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#adding-documents).

You need to be careful when using `set` as, by default, it replaces all the content of your existing record with the new one. `.set()` is useful in cases where you want to Create a new document with custom ID instead of the auto-generated one by `.add()`, preferably, if your sole goal is to update some fields in an existing document, use `.update()` instead, and note that:

1. `.update()` will fail if the document doesn't exist.
2. `.update()` can be used if you have nested data so it gives better updating capabilities.

---

So, to add more items to an array property in Firestore, you would use `.update()` like this:

```dart
atributteSheet.doc(uid).update({'armas': FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)})
```

List items should be one of the types Firestore accepts, such as a Map or a String, so you should convert your list by mapping each item from `Aramas` your user-defined type, to a `Map` type.

Comment: thanks for commenting, i've been stuck on this for a while. My goal is to create more then one field in the database. I try the way you showed me, but i was able to create just one field. In the end, if is possible, i want to create more fields.

https://prnt.sc/nSh1tMjZa5ML (image from my firebase)

Comment: You want to add more items to `armas` array, correct?

Comment: In this case, you can use `.update()` like this: `atributteSheet.doc(uid).update({'armas': FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)})`

Comment: i'm getting this error: Error: Invalid argument (dartObject): Could not convert: Instance of 'Armas'

Comment: `'armas': FieldValue.arrayUnion(armas),` Then, when i call the method (using a button for exemple, or field to write the data) i'm using this code: `armas: [
          Armas(modelo: 'AK-47', preco: 2342, numero: 22),
          Armas(modelo: 'M4A1', preco: 2342, numero: 232),
        ],`

Comment: You should convert the `Aramas` object to a `Map` as Firestore will not accept your user-defined type.